# tensorflow.string_input_producer 'hello world'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I can't get the following string_input_producer-`hello world` program to run:

```
import tensorflow as tf

filename = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.string, name='filename')
f_q = tf.train.string_input_producer(filename, num_epochs=1, shuffle=False)
filename_tf = f_q.dequeue()

with tf.Session() as S:
    S.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

    print(S.run(filename_tf, feed_dict={filename: "hello world"}))

    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
```

Seems simple enough, but tf tells me in an error message that i need to pass a string value to placeholder 'filename' (which I do).  Anyone gets what I'm doing wrong here?   Thanks

> Why does it say paper jam, when there is no paper jam!

Answer (score 0):

This can work.

```
import tensorflow as tf

filename = ['hello world']
f_q = tf.train.string_input_producer(filename, num_epochs=1, shuffle=False)
filename_tf = f_q.dequeue()

with tf.Session() as S:
    S.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

    print(S.run(filename_tf))

    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
```

because `tf.train.string_input_producer` returns a [queue](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/threading_and_queues) and it needs some real things to enqueue, then it will dequeue with some order.

Comment: [They](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/string_input_producer) say that `tf.train.string_input_producer` can take a tensor in API 1.3.  How can I make that work?

Comment: `tf.train.string_input_producer(tf.convert_to_tensor(a_list_of_strings))`, maybe this is what you want?

Comment: Thanks, @seven;  yeah that would be another solution for the minimal example I gave.  However, in my use case I would really like to pass a `tf.placeholder` into the `tf.string_input_producer` that is filled later on, just as in the example that I can't get to work.  This approach would have some advantages for my use case.